# android editText keyboard changed after setText()

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

If I want to enter a message into an editText, I enter some digits and my keyboard looks like that:

[image]

but after I add some text from code by clicking the button (`et.setText(et.getText().toString() + " " + "abc")`), keyboard changes to:
[image]

is there a way to prevent this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used editable.append instead of et.setText() and this works

Comment: how can i keep  the spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You should set input type in your EditText (for example by using "android:inputType" in xml file containing the layout).

See:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

Comment: in both screenshots, inputType is the same (text), you can't differentiate them.