# edittext.settext() changes the keyboard type to default [ from ?123 to ABC]

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have following code for my edittext formatting, since it can take any input I am not setting any input type:

```
if (cardNumberEditText != null) {
    cardNumberEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int currSel = cardNumberEditText.getSelectionStart();
            cardNumberEditText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            .
            .
            cardNumberEditText.setText(formattedNumber);
            .
            .
            cardNumberEditText.setSelection(currSel);
            cardNumberEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

So initially I get the default input type which is ABC, now when I change it to ?123 (using ABC/123? toggel button) and after entering some number the keyboard changes back to ABC. This code seams to work fine on samsung devices s3 and sywpe but not on nexus with L and HTC one

When I comment all the code inside onTextChanged, it works fine. So when I investigated I found out that culprit is cardNumberEditText.setText(formattedNumber);

I am not setting any input type, I am just using the ABC/?123 toggle key on keyboard for switching

Any help/suggestion why this is happening (on few devices) and how can I correct it ??

Comment: Aren't you telling it to bring up the numeric keyboard by inputting a number?  Or am I not understanding?

Comment: no i am not telling it by writing any code for input type, I am using the keyboad key ABC/123 to switch between them

Comment: finally found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11444544/2245895), will try it out

Comment: unfortunately the above one doesn't work well with me, any other better solution ???

Comment: found one [more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10119112/2245895) solution, using append instead of settext, but still doesn't work with my case, as I am doing card formatting I need to settext at the end

Answer (score 41, accepted):

finnaly got it working, had to combine multiple solutions mentioned in the comments above

since the guilty was settext, I found a replacement for it - append

but to use append I had to clear edittext without using settext, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967404/how-to-empty-edittext-without-settext) to the rescue

so replaced

```
cardNumberEditText.setText(formattedNumber);
```

with

```
cardNumberEditText.getText().clear();
cardNumberEditText.append(formattedNumber);
```

works like a charm now

Comment: append helped me in my scenerio.->edittext which has some a input enetered.settext will remove/clears the entire input.replacing with new settext value. use append if you dont want input to be removed.

Comment: Unfortunately this causes Galaxy S III 4.3 not to clear previous text properly and buggy device appends the text twice, but I get good results with `s.replace(0, s.length(), formatted, 0, formatted.length());` in `afterTextChanged(Editable s) `.

Comment: Append method is fixing the keyboard switching behaivor. But there is a minor problem. My edittext is numeric because I want to prevent user entering anything but numbers. When I used settext I could set a text that contains space character. When I use append it doesn't allow me to append anything but numbers 8(

Comment: You saved my day

Comment: @EvrenOzturk this will be fixed by adding `android:digits="0123456789 "` to the xml, apparently whatever you append gets filtered with `android:inputType` but the filter will be "OR"ed with `android:digits`

Comment: You saved our day!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but keyboard was changed to default after I call
`scrollView.fullScroll(NestedScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN)` when keyboard is shown
I just replaced `fullScroll` method to `smoothScrollTo` and all work fine

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, if anyone else struggles with cursor moving to the end after `.append()`, here is how you can retain cursor position:

```
val cursor = editText.selectionEnd
editText.text?.clear()
editText.append(input)
editText.setSelectionSafe(cursor)
```

where `setSelectionSafe()` is an extension I use to prevent crushes

```
fun EditText?.setSelectionSafe(index: Int) {
    if (this == null || index > this.length()) return
    this.setSelection(index)
}
```

this works both for entering and deleting !