# The keyboard resets itself after every single input

Tags: android, textwatcher

So far believe this has something to do with the `TextWatcher` Class.

Whenever I start typing in the `EditText` box field, the keyboard just resets itself.

If I want to type a full caps word, I have to press my caps again an again after every word input. Same goes with the numbers, when I switch to numerical input after I press any number, the keyboard goes back to the normal qwerty pad.

I want the keyboard to be consistent while typing.

Any help is appreciated.

Below is my `TextWatcher` Class.

```
public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private static final String TAG = "MyTextWatcher";
    private View view;
    EditText qtyView;

    public MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged: " + "before");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: " + "onTextChanged");

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();

        qtyView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtFillupDetails);
        ListViemItems listItems = (ListViemItems) qtyView.getTag();

        if (!listItems.getEditTextVal().equals(qtyString)) {

            listItems.setEditTextVal(qtyString);
            if (!listItems.getEditTextVal().equals("")) {

                int position = qtyView.getSelectionStart();
                qtyView.setText(listItems.getEditTextVal());

                qtyView.setSelection(qtyString.toString().trim().length());

            } else {
                qtyView.setText("");
            }
        }

        return;
    } 
}
```

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="7dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFillupDetails"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtFillupDetails"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_croner"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/registrnpadding"
            android:shadowRadius="2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my manifest file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lunetta.etro.e_tro">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo1"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Fillup_Details"
            android:label="Pre-Departure Details"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>       
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: looks okay to me. Have you used focusable and input type in your layout file ??

Comment: I've tried both the things in the layout file, but they have no affect on this.

Comment: Okay. Use editText.requestFocus() in afterTextChanged of TextWatcher. It is dirty but might just work for you.

Comment: nope, it didn't.

Comment: can you post your layout xml and manifest here.

Comment: yes, edited the question

Comment: The text watcher is inside MainActivity ??

Comment: no, the TextWatcher is being called in the ListAdapter class of the MainActivity.

Comment: Remove stateHidden from in manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"  and add android:focusable ="true" and android:inputType="text" inside ur EditText

Comment: ok, I said it wrong, the MainActivity which you asked isn't that. The TextWatcher is applied for the Fillup_Details Activity.

Comment: try the other two things.

Comment: However, the android:focusable ="true" and android:inputType="text" aren't working

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in another thread:

[edittext.settext() changes the keyboard type to default [ from ?123 to ABC]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365808/edittext-settext-changes-the-keyboard-type-to-default-from-123-to-abc)

The problem is in `editText.setText(text)` part of code which refreshes the keyboard. To fix it try this:

```
editText.getText().clear()
editText.append(text)
```

Hope will help anybody!)