# Update EditText content without resetting input method state

Tags: android, android-edittext

Well, the title may sound complicated, but it's not.
I just want to update `EditText` text without notifying the input method. I am using `editText.setSelection(getCursor);` but, for instance, if I am in special characters menu and I write something, keyboard jumps back to normal characters (a-z). Without `setSelection` I can continue in typing digits and special characters. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to "restore the keyboard state (whether emoji or last selected language), but unfortunately that's **NOT** possible.

> Is there any workaround for this issue?

Not really, but what you can do is [prepare a custom emoji keyboard](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji) and open if programmatically. But this approach also has a loophole, you won't be able to track user's current selection of its keyboard. I mean you won't know whether user selected emojiKeyboard or normalKeyboard and you'll end up opening emojiKeyboard every-time. **BUT** what you can do is check the last input inside the `editText` by the user and then open your own emojiKeyboard but again, what is user switched his/her keyboard style?

**[EDITED]** (asnwers to questions from comments)

> Why can't activity keep the keyboard state?

Because the keyboard developers didn't provide any callback as such, plus keyboard is some sort of third-party application which and can vary from devices to devices so it wasn't feasible

> Also, what about spanning text using Editable instance. Will activity keep keyboard state if I will just span existing text?

**NO** Activity will just not keep the state

Comment: Yeah, but why this occurs? I'm just updating text, why can't activity keep keyboard state?

Comment: Also, what about spanning text using Editable instance. Will activity keep keyboard state if I will just span existing text?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365808/edittext-settext-changes-the-keyboard-type-to-default-from-123-to-abc found answer here, however, edittext.clear() causes masive lag

Comment: Why can't activity keep the keyboard state?  Because the keyboard developers didn't provide any callback as such, plus keyboard is some sort of third-party application which and can vary from devices to devices so it wasn't feasible

Comment: *"Also, what about spanning text using Editable instance. Will activity keep keyboard state if I will just span existing text? "* **NO**  Activity will just not keep the state

Comment: I'm not sure why is it producing lag, there might be some other issue. It shouldn't produce any lag though!

Comment: for me it seems like android is trying to redraw edittext on `edittext.clear()` but it's disturbed by span operation

Comment: Nope, it has nothing to do with redrawing your EditText. Are you performing any action on TextChangeListener?

Comment: yes I am spanning that text in TextWatcher, however I am protecting app for going into loop using variable which is reset after text is changed and I am pretty sure it's not lag caused by loop. It looks more like big drawing operations.

Comment: I have tried profiling app and I am very confused. SpannableStringBuilder.replace() method is taking 140 ms and whenever I type something to edittext, WORD is copied after itself, so it's duplicating word after every key press event. It's happening only on words, not whole text so I think text is somehow spanned or editted also by input method after I clear and append text..

Comment: Both the approaches you are following will lead to delay due to actions you are performing, try adding a timer/delay before you perform such task. Don’t just update your editText right away.

Comment: Fixed duplicating words with textNoSuggestions

Comment: Yay!! :)  I'm glad you were able to get what you wanted :)

Comment: I am still not satisfied with result, however I eventually understood that EditText is complicated class and I will have to find another way if I want to implement full syntax highlighting and methods folding. Thank you for help anyway.

Comment: I would love to help you more, `dakshg18@gmail.com`  email me here :)